# ubuntu wordpress directories

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

I've tried installing Wordpress several times (like over 5) now in Ubuntu with apt-get.  Before each attempt, I do an apt-get --purge remove wordpress, then drop the database and delete the wordpress user from mysql.

When I install, I've tried various combinations of the setup-mysql script, as well as instructions from the wordpress site.  What happens is that I have three locations for wp-content related directories:
   /var/lib/wordpress
   /usr/share/wordpress
   /srv/www/wp-content

I'm not sure the proper configuration I should be using for my Apache directives.

The symptom of the problem is that upgrading plugins, or installing anything through the wordpress admin web panel results in errors such as:
could not install plugin, resulting in fatal error
could not upgrade, can not create directory

I've tried various permissions, going so far as 777, and chowning everything to www-data:www-data.

There must be a simple concise set of directions somewhere to get this set up properly.

Comment: I wasn't aware that WordPress could be installed with apt-get in Ubuntu. My recommendation is to install Apache, PHP, and MySQL from packages and then install WordPress manually.  The setup process is famously quick and the Ubuntu package will almost certainly lag behind the latest version. Running the current version of WordPress is recommended for security.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I downloaded the latest version and used instructions to install manually.  It works as expected now.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear it.